# using scanf function with asm language

Tags: c, assembly, scanf

```
extern printf
extern scanf
global main

section .text
main:
    sub rsp, 0x10
    mov rbx, rsp
    add rbx, 0x08
    mov rdi, format1
    mov rsi, rbx
    xor rax, rax
    call scanf
    mov rdi, format2
        mov rsi, [rbx]
        xor rax, rax
        call printf
    add rsp, 0x10
    ret
format1:
    db "%d", 0
format2:
    db "%d", 0xa, 0
value:
    dd 0xa
```

Above source is same with

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int tmp;
    scanf("%d", &tmp);
    printf("%d\n", tmp);
}
```

It works well. But I have question. If I change my source code to

```
extern printf
extern scanf
global main

section .text
main:
    mov rdi, format1
    mov rsi, value
    xor rax, rax
    call scanf
    mov rdi, format2
        mov rsi, [value]
        xor rax, rax
        call printf
    ret
format1:
    db "%d", 0
format2:
    db "%d", 0xa, 0
value:
    dd 0xa
```

it makes segmentation fault. I think there are no difference between above source code and first one. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: Have you stepped through with a debugger like GDB?

Comment: In results it says core is dumped, however I can't found core file. Without core file I don't know how to use gdb to analyze program with is written in nasm

Comment: `gdb ./nameofprogram` then use `layout asm` and then `layout reg` and set a break point on main with `b main` , start the program with `run` and then use `ni` to step instruction by instruction? Or use a graphical frontend for GDB like `ddd`?

Comment: When I execute `call scanf` segmentation fault occur. However I passed format string to `rdi` and address of value to `rsi`. So I can't understand why scanf makes error

Comment: Okay, this might be a bit difficult to see in a debugger but consider this. You placed `value` in the `.text` section. `.text` is read only. What would happen if you read data into a memory location that is read only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first code, you're allocating space for a variable (the `tmp` in your C code, unnamed in the asm code) on the stack and passing the address of it to the `scanf` function, then passing the value that `scanf` wrote there to `printf`.

In the second, you're trying to use a global `value` allocated in the `.text` section instead, but .text is read-only by default on most systems.  So when scanf tries to write to it, you get a segfault.

Stick a `section .data` just before `value:` to put it in the data section instead and it should be fine...